# How to find voltage across the resistor?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, resistors, transformer, homework

[image]

How to calculate the voltage V0 across the 8ohm resistor?
Using mesh analysis I get an answer(120V) which is different from the correct answer.

Left loop,
$$4I_1+V_1=120$$
Right loop,
$$10I_2+2I_3+V_2=0$$
Outer loop,
$$-120+4I_1+8I_3-8I_2=0$$

Solving I get,
$$I_3=15A \text{ and }V_0=120V$$

Comment: Is any data given about the transformer? Pleas [edit] the question to show the steps that you have followed.

Comment: Also, please use [MathJax](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5565/most-common-mathjax-uses-in-electrical-engineering) to format equations nicely.  Make clear your effort up to point stuck and ask help to get unstuck, not expecting free homework service.

Comment: Which 8 ohm resistor?

Comment: @HotLicks The one which is connected to both primary and secondary side. And \$V_0\$ is the voltage across the resistor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect the transformer is ideal, and it is where you may be stuck.  *Current into a polarity dot on one side means current out of the dot on other side*.  Their magnitude will be exactly per turns ratio.

So, draw an arrow going into left side dot and assign it a current variable. Then draw an arrow coming out of the other dot (or in to non-polarity dot side if easier) and assign it the **same** current variable, but scale it by \$1/2\$.  Also, assign a voltage variable to one side, scale it and assign with appropriate polarity on the other side as well. Then you can write KVL and KCL equations to solve.

[image]

Below I have assigned variables that should help you write the needed equations,

[image]

Comment: I'm able to find the current flowing in the secondary winding. But I'm confused about the voltage across the 8ohm resistor because it is connected to both primary and the secondary winding. Should I consider another current I3 and solve for it?

Comment: Yes, and it will fit nicely into the two node equations.  Also add voltage variable across your transformer to help you write KVL equations. I added a picture to clarify.

Comment: How should I take the equation for 8ohm resistor connected to both primary and secondary circuit? Should V1 and V2 be included in the equation?

Comment: I would write KVL equations for left loop, right loop, and then  an overall loop around perimeter of entire circuit.  That, with the two node equations should suffice.  You can edit your question to show us your equations.

Comment: For left loop: 4*I1 +V1 =120
      
For right loop: 10*I2 + 2*I3+ V2=0                     

Outer loop: -120 + 4*I1 + 8*I3-8*I2=0                 

where I1 and I2 are mesh currents of left and right in clock wise and anticlockwise direction resp. I3 is the current flowing through the 8ohm resistor.
On solving these equations I get I3=15A and V0=8*15=120V.
I'm not able to figure out the mistake.

Comment: I edited your question to show how to put those equations in with MathJax.  If accepted, it will show up shortly.  Your left loop equation ignores the voltage across the ideal transformer.  Look at the picture in my answer and include it.  There is only one loop current through the 2Ω resistor.  I will draw a suggested circuit for you to write equations for - please edit your question to show the equations you get.  You will get it, keep pecking away.

Comment: I assumed V1 as the voltage instead of Vx.
But current also flows through 8ohm resistor right? So shouldn't we assume a current I3 which flows in that loop?

Comment: See if my edit (added circuit with suggested variables) helps.  The current up through the  bottom right 8Ω resistor (from KCL) is \$\frac{i_2}{2}+i_3\$.

Comment: Actually, I assumed current flowing through left loop as \$i_1\$ . After seeing your circuit I got it clarified. Now I'm getting the correct answer 48V.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116752/discussion-between-relayman357-and-rakshith-krish).